Change columns of specific dataframe using another dataframe
I have a specific dataframe (df1) with some values for a variable called "MP10".
df = data = {
  "day": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
  "month": [1, 1, 4, 4, 7, 7, 7],
  "year": [2015, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2019, 2019,],
  "mp10": [10, 15, 20, 5, 7, 14, 18]  
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df)
df1

But, I have to change the values for NaN for specific days.
And I created another dataframe (df2), to find these specific days.
df = data = {
  "day": [2, 5, 7],
  "month": [1, 7, 7],
  "year": [2015, 2017, 2019,],
  "mp10": [np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN]  
}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(df)
df2

I thought that using pd.merge, I could change the values, but it didn't work.
How could I pick the NaN from df2 and change them in df1?

Images of data are not acceptable, you must provide a [mre] and a clear description of the logic.

I thought that putting the images from my dataframe could help. But I'll change it

@DanielMM it's not that having the data is (are?) unhelpful, it's just difficult for us to work with data presented as images. Being able to copy/paste helps immensely. What have you tried so far? It's also hard to debug code we don't have.

In addition data with ... is ambiguous, better craft a small but meaningful example and provide the matching expected output

I created an example. Maybe it works better than those images.

what is your expected output?

I expected to have the column "MP10" like this: [10, NaN, 20, 5, NaN, 14, NaN]

Thanks, it's much more explicit now.

You could use a merge with indicator=True to identify the indices to remove:
idx = (df1.reset_index()
       .merge(df2, on=['day', 'month', 'year'],
              how='left', indicator=True)
       .query('_merge == "both"')['index']
      )

df1.loc[idx, 'mp10'] = None

Variant using boolean indexing:
mask = (df1.merge(df2, on=['day', 'month', 'year'],
                  how='left', indicator=True)
        ['_merge'].eq('both')
        .tolist() # merge doesn't maintain the index
       )

df1.loc[mask, 'mp10'] = None

Output:
   day  month  year  mp10
0    1      1  2015  10.0
1    2      1  2015   NaN
2    3      4  2016  20.0
3    4      4  2017   5.0
4    5      7  2017   NaN
5    6      7  2019  14.0
6    7      7  2019   NaN

Or, if you want a new DataFrame:
out = (df1.merge(df2.assign(mp10=1), on=['day', 'month', 'year'],
                 how='left', suffixes=(None, '_mask'))
          .assign(mp10=lambda x: x['mp10'].mask(x.pop('mp10_mask').eq(1)))
      )


Great! It worked! I didn't know about ".query", but I'll read and learn more about it.

I was looking at this code again, and noted that it didn't work perfectly. For some reason, when df1 had a number, it didn't change for NaN

@Daniel can you be more explicit?

I created another answer, and explained there. Thanks for your help

@DanielMM don't use an answer, edit your question and add you nex example after the existing one. Also, don't use images of data, rather provide the two inputs (df1/df2) as DataFrame constructors, like currently done for the first example.

Ok, i'll change it. Thanks!

I looked at the code and realized that I was wrong and committed a mistake. Sorry about it.

You can just set a datetime index yourself and use it:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "day": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
        "month": [1, 1, 4, 4, 7, 7, 7],
        "year": [2015, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2019, 2019],
        "mp10": [10, 15, 20, 5, 7, 14, 18],
    }
)

df = df.assign(datetime=pd.to_datetime(df[["day", "month", "year"]]))
df = df.set_index("datetime")

to_change = pd.to_datetime(
    {"day": [2, 5, 7], "month": [1, 7, 7], "year": [2015, 2017, 2019]}
)

df.loc[to_change, "mp10"] = np.nan

>>> df
            day  month  year  mp10
datetime
2015-01-01    1      1  2015  10.0
2015-01-02    2      1  2015   NaN
2016-04-03    3      4  2016  20.0
2017-04-04    4      4  2017   5.0
2017-07-05    5      7  2017   NaN
2019-07-06    6      7  2019  14.0
2019-07-07    7      7  2019   NaN

